# Detect if link opens in a new window/tab or the current window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add AJax-like transitions to my links if a link opens in the current window. However, I don't want the transitions to execute if the link is opened in a new window/new tab. Is this possible?

P.S. I have jQuery loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user opens a link in a new window/tab (via middle click, ctrl click or right-click->new window), the browser will automatically ignore any `onclick` handler and simply open a new tab/window pointing at the URL specified by the link's `href` attribute.

You don't have to do anything special to prevent your AJAX from firing, so long as you're correctly specifying real `href` attributes for your anchor tags.

You can easily verify this yourself: The edit link on your question loads content via AJAX. If you middle/ctrl-click it, the URL `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10215887/edit` will be loaded into a new window. If you click it normally, JavaScript will intercept the click and load the form inline without a page refresh.

Comment: `onclick` is ignored with right click->new window. But with ctrl+left click, the transition still runs. I'm using Chrome btw.

Comment: @Linksku You can check pretty easily if they'd held `ctrl` in your `click` callback function, though. Do you need to consider links that have `click` event handlers calling `window.open()`?